# Angular 2 routing raising 404 errors

Tags: angular, iis-7, angular2-routing, url-routing

**HTML5 PushState** means *refresh URL or enter direct URL in browser*  works  perfectly fine when I run my angular app using `'npm start'` command from VS 2015 command prompt. However when I deploy same application on IIS and change  `<base href="/"/>` to `<base href="/MyVirtualApplication/" />` then **HTML5's PushState** or **History API** doesn't work properly and raising 404 error.

Please do suggest.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34541532/is-angular-2s-router-broken-when-using-html5-routes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Resolve In Angular2 Routes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33462532/using-resolve-in-angular2-routes)

Comment: I do not think my question is duplicate. Everywhere it is mentioned about handling the requests using alternative ways or using # techniques. I tried some other blogs which mention about `npm lite server` however I am unable to get answer what changes I need to have if I am deploying my app on IIS server. Each time I cannot run `npm lite` e.g. on QA server or staging.

Comment: Try to redirect the route in IIS from MyVirtualApplication.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I Think I got my answer after basic understanding on nodejs and use of it with Angular2.

Basically, nodejs - expressjs itself is a web server and when we execute a command npm start web server starts and listing on a port which is defined. And it does not require any additional server.

Comment: @DiegoUnanue, basically angular 2.0 run on node. so when you are running your app on local it always has to run thru npm.

Comment: Check [this](https://admin-ahead.com/blog/node-js-installation-windows-2008-r2-server/)

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: IIS Setup for Url Rewriting:

You need to install this to make the following work: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

First Step:
[image]

Second Step:
[image]

I found a link which explains the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12614072/

**OLD**:

While running any application built with Angular 2 outside of the development environment setup by `npm`, you have to replace `<base href="/">` with this:

```
<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
```

**Note**: This is only for production or if running out of the `npm` environment.

Comment: I tried this same. and when I implementing this thru IIS, I am having issues. Just for my knowledge, have you tried from both `npm lite` and from `IIS` ? and it is running without any issues for you?

Comment: @Avinash - I don't have **IIS** but I've found a solution. Check the edit to my answer.

Comment: I think I have tough time with IIS and this HTML5 feature. I tried exactly same mention by your comments however no luck and on top of that link provided you is not available. Either broken or incomplete. I think for time being I have to go with `npm lite` server. 
Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: After struggling with asp.net core request rewrite and mvc etc, I came over this solution. And I must say I like it very much. This way I don't have to publish the enormous Core app just for the silly request rewriting, and it is much easier to configure.