# Angular2- When refresh the page, url remains same but appropriate view doesn't get loaded

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In Angular2, I am facing this issue. When you refresh the page. The URL remains same but it doesn't load appropriate view in `RouterOutlet`.

***Everything works fine except refreshing page issue.***

**app.ts**

```
import {Component,bind} from 'angular2/core';

import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {FORM_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/form';
import{HomeCmp} from 'Angular/src/Home/home.ts';
import {ContactUsCmp} from 'Angular/src/ContactUs/contactus.ts';

import {Router,ROUTER_PROVIDERS,RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,APP_BASE_HREF,LocationStrategy,RouteParams,ROUTER_BINDINGS} from 'angular2/router';
@Component({
selector: 'micropuppy-app',
templateUrl: "ANGULAR/Templates/home.html",
directives:[HomeCmp,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,ContactUsCmp],
template: ` <nav>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    **<li><a [routerLink]="['Home']">One</a><hr/></li>
                     <li><a [routerLink]="['ContactUs']">Contact Us</a></li>**
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Technologies <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Angular</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">.NET</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>`
 })

@RouteConfig([
  {path:'/Home', name: 'Home', component: HomeCmp}
  {path:'/ContactUs', name: 'ContactUs', component: ContactUsCmp}
])

export class MicropuppyApp {
    constructor(){
        console.log("Micropuppy app started");
    }
}
 bootstrap(MicropuppyApp, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS,bind(APP_BASE_HREF).toValue(location.pathname)]);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2.0 router not working on reloading the browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415052/angular-2-0-router-not-working-on-reloading-the-browser)

Answer (score 2):

With the default strategy (HTML5 history API) of routing, you need a server configuration to redirect all your paths to your HTML entry point file. With the hashbang approach it's not necessary... If you want to switch to this approach, simply use the following code:

```
import { bootstrap } from "angular2/platform/browser";
import { provide } from "angular2/core";
import {
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy
} from "angular2/router";

bootstrap(MainApp, [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass:HashLocationStrategy});
]);
```

You could have a look at these questions about this issue:

- [When I refresh my website I get a 404. This is with Angular2 and firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34415725/when-i-refresh-my-website-i-get-a-404-this-is-with-angular2-and-firebase/34416946#34416946)
- [PathLocationStrategy vs HashLocationStrategy in web apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34703343/pathlocationstrategy-vs-hashlocationstrategy-in-web-apps/34703613#34703613)
- [Is Angular 2's Router broken when using HTML5 routes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34541532/is-angular-2s-router-broken-when-using-html5-routes/34543822#34543822)

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: it works as expected. but with this approach, it adds `#` symbol which doesn't look good for real application. I have already added `<base href="/">`. Please guide.

Comment: Yes, in fact, having the # symbol is the prize for not having something to do on the server  side :-( I agree with you that URLs with the hashbang approach aren't as clean as with the `PathLocationStrategy` (default one). But if you need the later, it's necessary to have the redirection stuff on the server side. It depends on your server platform. Firebase allows to do this in a few lines of code ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Even I was stuck in the same situation where on refresh Angular2 app was failing to load.

The reason behind this issue is Angular2 router uses history API for routing due to which on the refresh of route App unable to find index.html and end up showing 404 or can not GET requested URL.

you can work around in two ways:

1. Hashbang technique by using HashLocationStrategy but URL looks bad due to present of hash.
2. Here how I worked it out:

I use Node.js for serving the request.

Assuming you have Node and Npm installed.

**package.json** for installing required modules.

```
{
  "name": "Express server",
  "version": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.14.0"
  }
}
```

create **server.js** in your project directory.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('dist')); 
// 'dist' is my build folder, you can add yours. this will take care of all static files.

app.use('/*', express.static('dist/index.html')); 
// This will make sure that every route should serve index.html first 

app.listen(8080, function () {
    console.log('app listening on port 8080!!')
});
```

Use the following command to start your app server.

```
node server.js
```

Now every request will go through your App server which will make sure that on every refresh/reload index.html get served which will boost angular App.

Comment: you're great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this issue by putting this code on the top of head in the `index.html` under `<title>` put

```
<script>document.write('<base href="/" />');</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right answer but
On-refresh you can redirect all dead calls to Homepage by sacrificing 404 page
it's a temporary hack just replay following on 404.html file

```
   <!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.location.href = "http://" + document.location.host;
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don' want # means, go with 'PathLocationStrategy'. It is somewhat similar to HashLocationStratedy.
Hope, this link will help you [Angular2 routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35052663/routing-and-navigation-in-angular-2/35057576#35057576).

Comment: I thought that you missed something.Follow the steps mentioned in that link. It works fine for me.