# angular2 IIS url rewrite

Tags: angular, iis, url-rewriting

I have angular2 app. After publish it on IIS when I refresh browser I'm getting 404 error.

As I found [here](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/07/26/angularjs-enable-html5-mode-page-refresh-without-404-errors-in-nodejs-and-iis) I add web.config file in my dist folder (where I have published my app)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <configuration>
 <system.web>
 </system.web>
 <system.webServer><rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="AngularJS" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{index.html}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{index.html}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

and here is my folder

[image]

**But** now after refresh I'm getting

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
>   The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

What's wrong?

(I know about `HashLocationStrategy` and I don't want to use that)

Comment: Which url you try to navigate?

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat in url where browser is currently. for example if user will click refresh in domain.com/about it should not give 404 error

Comment: 500.19 - error is due to invalid rewrite input="{index.html}"

Comment: If I leave it to {REQUEST_FILENAME} result is same

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35052663/routing-and-navigation-in-angular-2

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat I have tried that too. result is same

Comment: What is your base href?

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat It seems I had not installed url rewrite module. now it works thanks for help