# Provide async dependencies to route's generic components in Angular 2. Route's resolve equivalent

Tags: javascript, routes, components, angular

I want to provide a set of **generic** components, so they will be *not aware of services that provides dependencies*. Dependencies such components are promises. 
In other words I want to keep for instance data access *out of the scope of those generic components*. Any dependencies, especially data to render and component configuration should be *provided to components* by the context that are declaring the component. 
This is easy when I declare component in *view* as a DOM tag e.g.:

`<generic-component data="getSomeData()" configuration="componentConfig"></generic-component>`

**But how I can handle that when component is invoked directly be the route?**

**I've read [very similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33462532/using-resolve-in-angular2-routes) but answer for the question definitely did not satisfy me. Accepted answer advice to put dependencies into component, but that means losing generic manner of component.**

**In Angular 1 approach to do so was by using `resolve` property of route declaration. What is equivalent of Angular's 1 resolve in Angular 2?**

Please refer to the [mentioned question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33462532/using-resolve-in-angular2-routes) example cause it's very accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular 2 in RC 4 introduced [resolve](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Resolve-interface.html) property of Route.

This property is object with properties which implements Resolve interface.

Each resolver must be [@Injectable](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#angular-dependency-injection) and has method resolve which return Observable|Promise|any.

When You inject ActivatedRoute as `route` into component You can access each resolved property from route.snapshod.data['someResolveKey'].

Example from angular.io doc:

```
class Backend {
  fetchTeam(id: string) {
    return 'someTeam';
  }
}
@Injectable()
class TeamResolver implements Resolve<Team> {
  constructor(private backend: Backend) {}
  resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<any>|Promise<any>|any {
    return this.backend.fetchTeam(route.params.id);
  }
}
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'team/:id',
        component: TeamCmp,
        resolve: {
          team: TeamResolver
        }
      }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [TeamResolver]
})
class AppModule {}
```

Or You can also provide a function with the same signature instead of the class.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'team/:id',
        component: TeamCmp,
        resolve: {
          team: 'teamResolver'
        }
      }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'teamResolver',
      useValue: (route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => 'team'
    }
  ]
})
class AppModule {}
```

And You can get data in component:

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
    resource : string;
    team : string;

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.team = this.route.snapshot.data['team'];

        // UPDATE: ngOnInit will be fired once,
        // even If you use same component for different routes.
        // If You want to rebind data when You change route
        // You should not use snapshot but subscribe on
        // this.route.data or this.route.params eg.:
        this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => this.resource = params['resource']);
        this.route.data.subscribe((data: any) => this.team = data['team']);
    }

}
```

Hope it helps,
happy hacking!

Answer (score 0):

I experience exactly the same issue.

Route's dedicated components which will holds generics components could be solutions. But this is not elegant, it is rather bypass then solution.