# Angular 2 on refresh binding is undefined

Tags: angular, angular2-template

ApplicationComponent:

```
@RouteConfig([
  {path:'/', name: 'Dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, useAsDefault: true},
  {path:'/model/:id', name: 'ModelDetail', component: ModelDetailComponent},
])
```

The visitor directly visit:
 http://localhost:8080/model/4

Before we can render "ModelDetailComponent", we need to load all models inside the class ngOnInit().

```
ngOnInit() {
    let id = parseInt(this.routeParams.get('id'));
    this.modelService.subject$.subscribe(models => {
      if ( models.length > 0 ) {
        this.model = models[0];
      }
    })
    this.modelService.getModel(id);
  }
```

template:

```
<h1>{{model.name}}</h1>
<model-list [model]="model"></model-list> //nested compnent that also use the model.
```

property

```
public model:IModel;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the [CanActivate](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/CanActivate-decorator.html) hook. It will allow you to wait  with component rendering until data is resolved (similar to Angular 1.x resolve feature).

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33462532/using-resolve-in-angular2-routes) for more details.

Comment: Yes,  it will wait with page load until data arrived, I guess this was your problem at first place, right?

Comment: @JamalJames cool, please mark my solution as the answer, if it solved your problem

Comment: I just did @YanivEfraim

Comment: @JamalJames cool! You can mark the the 'V' sign so people will know this was the right answer for you (:

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
<h1>{{model?.name}}</h1>
```

(added `?`) then it doesn't matter that the data arrives later.

If you have lots of such bindings it might be easier to wrap the whole template with `*ngIf`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template' `
    <div *ngIf="model">
      <h1>{{model.name}}</h1>`})
    <div>
class MyComponent {  }
```

Comment: I guess so but it's difficult without being able to reproduce. If you could provide a Plunker, I could verify if this is actually what solves your issue. Currently it's only a guess.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: It works, but the problem I have to do it on every component which is used on "RouteConfig" for specific URL!

Comment: The problem is that every component needs the json document before rendering the component. So I have to explicitly add "if switch" to every single component.

Comment: I think this is still the best way to make your components async-compatible. Usually not every async call is caused by navigation and route change.