# Waiting for ngrx action before loading page with URL parameter

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm building an ng2 application using ngrx. When the app is launched a web service is called to get initial data, once this data is fetched I create an *INIT_DONE* action.

My State looks like this :

```js
export interface State {
  documents: Document[];
  selectedDocument: Document
}
```

When I go to the page /mypage/456 where 456 is a url parameter, I need to get some of the fetched data so I get the URL parameter like this :

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.paramSubscription = this.route.params
    .select<string>('id')
    .map((id) => new SelectAction(id))
    .subscribe(this.store);
}
```

The *SELECT_ACTION* finds the element in the fetched data and sets `selectedDocument`. The problem is that the *SELECT_ACTION* is created before *INIT_DONE* and at that point `documents` is empty.

How do I wait for *INIT_DONE* before loading my page ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would make use of the [combineLatest](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html) operator as it combines the latest values of multiple source streams. In addition I'd double-check that documents is set (here I assumed it's an array) using filter.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.subscription = Observable.combineLatest(
      this.store.select("documents")
          .filter(documents => documents.length > 0),
      this.paramSubscription = this.route.params
          .select<string>('id')
  )
  .map((combinedData: [Object[], string]) => combinedData[1])
  .subscribe(this.store);
}
```

Also assign the subscription to a variable so that you can unsubscribe when the component is destroyed. Otherwise your subscription will be around after the component has been destroyed and it's possible that your action still gets emitted:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: There's a typo in _filter_ iteratee: _documents_ vs _document_.

Comment: @JakubBarczyk Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You need a resolver. A resolver waits until data is available before completing the navigation action.

```
@Injectable()
export class DocumentsResolver implements Resolve {

    constructor(
        private store: Store
    ) {}

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Hero> {
        // take id from snapshot
        const id = route.params['id'];
        // start with the document list
        return this.store.select('documents')
          // wait until there is data available
          .filter(documents => documents && documents.length > 0)
          // then produce the selected document
          .mergeMapTo(this.store.select('selectedDocument'));
    }
}
```

On route configuration:

```
export const DocumentsRoutes: RouterConfig = [
    { path: 'documents/:id', component: DocumentsDetailComponent, resolve: { document: DocumentsResolver } }
];
```

More about router resolve [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33462532/using-resolve-in-angular2-routes)

Comment: problem with resolver is that UI won't be shown it data is loaded... we cannot show some progress

Answer (score 0):

You could select documents from the store and subscribe to it and emit your action from there:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.store.select("documents").subscribe(documents => {
    this.paramSubscription = this.route.params
      .select<string>('id')
      .map((id) => new SelectAction(id))
      .subscribe(this.store);
  });  
}
```