# Confusion regarding observables merging based on their return

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, observable, ngrx

I am working on an angular2 application which uses ngrx store approach to manage states. App is open source on github [here](https://github.com/aviabird/travel-app/tree/master/src/app)

**Problem statement**

**Specific problem I am facing with this approach is using values emitted from one observable when other observable returns null**.

**I don't want to query backend api when I have data present in my ngrx  *store***.

---

**Angular2 Code**

Below is my `trips.reducer.ts` file

```
export interface State {
  ids: string[];
  trips: { [id: string]: Trip };
  selectedTripId: string;
}

const initialState = {
  ids: [],
  trips: {},
  selectedTripId: null
}

export function reducer(state = initialState, action: Action ): State {}

export function getTrips(state : State) {
  return state.trips;
} 

export function getTripIds(state: State) {
  return state.ids;
}

export function getSelectedTripId(state: State) {
  return state.selectedTripId;
}
```

Below is my base reducer `index.ts`

```
export interface State {
  trips: fromTripsReducer.State;    
} 

const reducers = {
  trips: fromTripsReducer.reducer,
}

export function getTripsState(state: State): fromTripsReducer.State {
  return state.trips;
}

export const getTrips = createSelector(getTripsState, fromTripsReducer.getTrips);
export const getTripIds = createSelector(getTripsState, fromTripsReducer.getTripIds);
export const getSelectedTripId = createSelector(getTripsState, fromTripsReducer.getSelectedTripId);
export const getSelectedCityId = createSelector(getTripsState, fromTripsReducer.getSelectedCityId);

export const getTripsCollection = createSelector(getTrips, getTripIds, (trips, ids) => {
  return ids.map(id => trips[id]);
});

export const getSelectedTrip = createSelector(getTrips, getSelectedTripId, (trips, id) => {
  return trips[id];
});
```

Now I can get a particular trip in `trip-detail.component.ts` like this

```
selectedTrip$: Trip;

constructor(private store: Store<fromRoot.State>) {
  this.selectedTrip$ = this.store.select(fromRoot.getSelectedTrip);
}
```

Now if  I reload the route `localhost:4200/trips/2`, then our store will initialize to initialState that is shown below

```
const initialState = {
  ids: [],
  trips: {},
  selectedTripId: null
}
```

and below method will not work as getTrips and getSelectedTripId will be null

```
export const getSelectedTrip = createSelector(getTrips, getSelectedTripId, (trips, id) => {
  return trips[id];
});
```

So now I can make a backend request which will load only the single trip based on the url id like this

```
return this.http.get(`${this.apiLink}/trips/${trip_id}.json`
  .map((data) => data.json())
```

But i want to make backend request only when the trip is not present in the store and

this.selectedTrip$ returns null or undefined.

```
this.selectedTrip$ = this.store.select(fromRoot.getSelectedTrip);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the data to be ready before the component is being shown you could use a resolver. See this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40922913/1353465).

In your case it would look the following and the resolver would only make sure that the loading of the data is initialized if `selectedTrip` is `null`. Note: As we won't use the returned data of the resolver anywhere, we can just return anything.

```
@Injectable()
export class SelectedTripResolver implements Resolve {

constructor(
    private store: Store
) {}

resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {

    // get the selectedTrip
    return this.store.select(fromRoot.getSelectedTrip)
        // check if data is ready. If not trigger loading actions
        .map( (selectedTrip) => {
            if (selectedTrip === null) {
                //trigger action for loading trips & selectedTrip
                this.store.dispatch(new LoadTripAction());
                this.store.dispatch(new LoadselectedTripAction());
                return false; // just return anything
            } else {
                return true; // just return anything
            }
        });
```

}

Here the resolver will make sure that the load actions are triggered when the `selectedTrip` data is not ready.

In the `trip-detail.component` you'll only need to wait for valid data. Like so:

```
constructor(private store: Store<fromRoot.State>) {
    this.selectedTrip$ = this.store.select(fromRoot.getSelectedTrip)
        .filter(selectedTrip => selectedTrip !== null);
}
```

Hope that makes sense and helps you.