# How to call a function after the completion of two Angular 2 subscriptions?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am on Angular 2.3.1 and I am fairly new to both Angular and event based programming. I have two subscriptions, `route.params.subscribe` and `engineService.getEngines()`. In my `onInit` I want to call `getEngineName` after `this.route.params.subscribe` and `this.engineService.getEngines().subscribe` complete.

Reason for this:  `getEngineName` functions depends on the `engineId` from the queryParams and the `engines` array which is populated after the completion of `getEngines()` call.

I did look at `flatMap` and `switchMap` but I did not completely understand them.

This is the code in the component:

```js
export class ItemListComponent implements OnInit {
  items: Item[];

  engines: Engine[];
  private engineId: number;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private itemService: ItemService,
    private engineService: EngineService
   ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.engineId = +params['engineId'];

      // itemService is irrelevant to this question 
      this.itemService.getItems({engineId: this.engineId})
        .subscribe((items: Item[]) => {
          this.items = items;
        });
    });

    this.engineService.getEngines()
      .subscribe(engines => this.engines = engines);

    // This should only run after engineId and engines array have been populated.
    this.getEngineName(this.engineId);
  }

  getEngineName(engineId: number) {
    this.engines.find((engine) => {
      return engine.id === engineId;
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: you could use combineLatest. Your problem is similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40872357/waiting-for-ngrx-action-before-loading-page-with-url-parameter/40905330#40905330 With combineLatest you don't need to nest subscriptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you just move the logic inside the `route.params` callback?

```
this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.engineId = +params['engineId'];

      // itemService is irrelevant to this question 
      this.itemService.getItems({engineId: this.engineId})
        .subscribe((items: Item[]) => {
          this.items = items;
        });

     //this.engineId is defined here (1)
     this.engineService.getEngines()
      .subscribe((engines) => {
         this.engines = engines;
         //this.engines is defined here (2)
         this.getEngineName(this.engineId);
     });
});
```

with `flatMap` and `forkJoin`:

```
this.route.params.flatMap((params: Params) => {
      this.engineId = +params['engineId'];    

      return Observable.forkJoin( 
         this.itemService.getItems({engineId: this.engineId}),
         this.engineService.getEngines()
      )          
}).subscribe((data)=>{
   let items = data[0];
   let engines = data[1];
   this.items = items;
   this.engines = engines;
   this.getEngineName(this.engineId);
});
```

Comment: Ah! Yes. This makes so much sense! Thanks a lot. This did it for me.

Comment: @Yathi glad I could help

Comment: just wondering as I don't know it any better: Are nested subscriptions ok in rxjs? I personally try to avoid them as I think the code is easier to read, but maybe I was mistaken.

Comment: @chrigu I'm not the right person to say that it is ok :-) but they are definitely not great. As you have mentioned you should use operators like `flatMap` or `forkJoin`. I'll update the question with the `flatMap` version also but since I don't know your whole architecture I didn't want to recommend anything.

Comment: @chrigu I've updated my answer with `flatMap` + `forkJoin` I might have messed up somewhere so be sure to check the return parameter (`data`). Hope it helps ;)

Comment: @echonax I admit that I had to look `forkJoin` up :). This should work if the forked streams terminate.

Answer (score 0):

`switchMap` is recommended in this scenario.

```
    this.route.params.pluck('engineId') //pluck will select engineId key from params
        .switchMap(engineId => {
            this.getItems(engineId);
            return this.engineService.getEngines().map(engines => {
                /*this.engineService.getEngines() emits the list of engines.
                  Then use map operator to convert the list of engines to engine we are looking for
                 */
                return engines.find((engine) => {
                    return engine.id === engineId;
                })
            })
        }).subscribe(engine => {
          //engine  
    })

    getItems(engineId) {
      this.itemService.getItems({engineId: engineId})
        .subscribe((items: Item[]) => {
          this.items = items;
        });
    }
```

Suppose the engineId in the params changes, the first observable `this.route.params.pluck('engineId')` will emit data, which will cause the next observable `this.engineService.getEngines()` to get fired. Now suppose the route changes before this observable emits the data. Here you need to cancel `getEngines` observable to prevent error. This is done by `switchMap`.

`switchMap` cancels inner observable if outer observable is fired.

PS: I have avoided keeping any states like `this.engineId` etc.

Comment: I don't follow this completely. Can you add some more comments in the code to make it more clear? Also, where would I be calling my `itemService.getItems()`? I assume it is before the return statement in the switchMap. Also why is this better than the first answer?